# Finding last character of base file name

Tags: shell-script

Say there are different files,

```
script.sh
text.txt
pic_1.png
```

or files with no extension - 'hello'.
How can you extract the last character of base file name?
ie,

```
script. sh - t
text.txt -  t
pic_1.png - p
hello - o
```

Is there like a simple way to do it?

Comment: `pic_1.png - p` example makes no sense within the scope of the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you remove the extension if any:

```
name_no_ext=${file%.*}
```

then, you get the last char:

```
char=${name_no_ext: -1} #note the space after colon
```

If you want to learn more about string manipulation in bash, go to section `Parameter Expansion` of the bash manual.

Answer (score 2):

POSIXLY:

```
for w in script.sh text.txt pic_1.png; do
  w=${w%.*}
  all_but_last_char=${w%?}
  w=${w##"$all_but_last_char"}
  printf '%s\n' "$w"
done
```

Note that it doesn't work with unicode characters in some shells like `mksh`, `dash`.